# Docker error: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Ran into this Docker error with one of my projects:

`invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase`

What are the various causes for this generic message?

I already figured it out after some effort, so I'm going to answer my own question in order to document it here as the solution doesn't come up right away when doing a web search and also because this error message doesn't describe the direct problem Docker encounters.

Comment: "reference" in this error message is the identifier of an image, as BMitch explained in his answer. So the format of the value you used to point to an image is invalid. Read BMitch's full explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52818152/336694

Answer (score 239, accepted):

A "reference" in docker is a pointer to an image. It may be an image name, an image ID, include a registry server in the name, use a sha256 tag to pin the image, and anything else that can be used to point to the image you want to run.

The `invalid reference format` error message means docker cannot convert the string you've provided to an image. This may be an invalid name, or it may be from a parsing error earlier in the `docker run` command line if that's how you run the image.

If the name itself is invalid, the `repository name must be lowercase` means you use upper case characters in your registry or repository name, e.g. `YourImageName:latest` should be `yourimagename:latest`.

With the `docker run` command line, this is often the result in not quoting parameters with spaces, missing the value for an argument, and mistaking the order of the command line. The command line is ordered as:

```
docker ${args_to_docker} run ${args_to_run} image_ref ${cmd_to_exec}
```

The most common error in passing args to the run is a volume mapping expanding a path name that includes a space in it, and not quoting the path or escaping the space. E.g.

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/data image_ref
```

Where if you're in the directory `/home/user/Some Project Dir`, that would define an anonymous volume `/home/user/Some` in your container, and try to run `Project:latest` with the command `Dir:/data image_ref`. And the fix is to quote the argument:

```
docker run -v "$(pwd):/data" image_ref
```

Other common places to miss quoting include environment variables:

```
docker run -e SOME_VAR=Value With Spaces image_ref
```

which docker would interpret as trying to run the image `With:latest` and the command `Spaces image_ref`. Again, the fix is to quote the environment parameter:

```
docker run -e "SOME_VAR=Value With Spaces" image_ref
```

With a compose file, if you expand a variable in the image name, that variable may not be expanding correctly. So if you have:

```yaml
version: 2
services:
  app:
    image: ${your_image_name}
```

Then double check that `your_image_name` is defined to an all lower case string.

Comment: "With the docker run command line, this is often the result in not quoting parameters with spaces, and mistaking the order of the command line" This was really helpful

Comment: The section explaining the need to quote the path `docker run -v "$(pwd):/data" image_ref` helped in my case.

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks! For anyone passing multiple environment variables to Docker, be aware that each var should receive their own "-e": `docker run -e "env_var1=value1" -e "env_var2=value2" image_name`

Comment: The problem here is that it is lower case, I'm not using any upper case letters anywhere in the image name and it's still giving me this error.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle you are likely looking at a different part of the command than docker is. The first thing that is not a parameter to a flag is treated as the image name, and the CLI is separated by spaces.

Answer (score 66):

In my case was the `-e` before the parameters for mysql docker

```
docker run --name mysql-standalone -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello -e MYSQL_DATABASE=hello -e MYSQL_USER=hello -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=hello -d mysql:5.6
```

Check also if there are missing whitespaces

Comment: Same with me, I was missing the `-e` before one of my environment variables.

Comment: in my case I forgot to export variable from external environment.

Comment: It was the missing whitspaces between -e and another variable.

Answer (score 49):

Let me emphasise that **Docker doesn't even allow mixed characters.**

**Good:** 
    `docker build -t myfirstechoimage:0.1 .`

**Bad:**
    `docker build -t myFirstEchoImage:0.1 .`

Comment: I am using "spotify" maven dependency in the SpringBoot project to build the docker image and from the last couple of hours, I was struggling to understand the issue. The name of the project (contains capital characters) to turn out to be the issue!

Answer (score 30):

had a space in the current working directory and usign `$(pwd)` to map volumes. Doesn't like spaces in directory names.

Comment: That solved it for me! I wrapped `$(pwd)` in quotes and it worked.

Comment: For me, I had to escape any space characters.

Comment: Uppercase letters in the working directory also causes this issue. rename the working directory to all lowercase letters.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the image name defined in `docker-compose.yml` contained uppercase letters. The fact that the error message mentioned `repository` instead of `image` did not help describe the problem and it took a while to figure out.

Comment: Another common cause found by searching the web was that people have space characters in their directory names when mounting volumes.

Comment: It happened to me for a different reason. The docker multi-stage build inside a Dockerfile as named with upper letters. 

Example: 
   `FROM bla:bla AS BUILD` failed. `FROM bla:bla AS build` was OK

Thx!

Answer (score 11):

In my case the problem was in parameters arrangement. Initially I had `--name` parameter after environment parameters and then volume and `attach_dbs`  parameters, and image at the end of command like below.

```
docker run -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=myComplexPwd -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y --name sql1 -v c:/temp/:c:/temp/ attach_dbs="[{'dbName':'TestDb','dbFiles':['c:\\temp\\TestDb.mdf','c:\\temp\\TestDb_log.ldf']}]" -d microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express
```

After rearranging the parameters like below everything worked fine (basically putting `--name` parameter followed by image name).

```
docker run -d -p 1433:1433 -e sa_password=myComplexPwd -e ACCEPT_EULA=Y --name sql1 microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express -v C:/temp/:C:/temp/ attach_dbs="[{'dbName':'TestDb','dbFiles':['C:\\temp\\TestDb.mdf','C:\\temp\\TestDb_log.ldf']}]"
```

Answer (score 7):

On MacOS when your are working on an iCloud drive, your $PWD will contain a directory "Mobile Documents". It does not seem to like the space!

As a workaround, I copied my project to local drive where there is no space in the  path to my project folder.

I do not see a way you can get around changnig the default path to iCloud which is `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs`

The space in the path in "Mobile Documents" seems to be what docker run does not like.

Comment: Instead of copying the project, you can escape the space e.g.  `Mobile\ Documents`

Answer (score 4):

A `reference` in Docker is what points to an image. This could be in a remote registry or the local registry. Let me describe the error message first and then show the solutions for this.

> invalid reference format

This means that the reference we have used is not a valid format. This means, the reference (pointer) we have used to identify an image is invalid. Generally, this is followed by a description as follows. This will make the error much clearer.

> invalid reference format: **repository name must be lowercase**

This means the reference we are using should not have uppercase letters. Try running `docker run Ubuntu` (**wrong**) vs `docker run ubuntu` (**correct**). Docker does not allow any uppercase characters as an image reference. Simple troubleshooting steps.

1) **Dockerfile** contains a capital letters as images.

```
FROM Ubuntu (wrong)
FROM ubuntu (correct)
```

2) Image name defined in the **docker-compose.yml** had uppercase letters

3) If you are using Jenkins or GoCD for deploying your docker container, please check the run command, whether the image name includes a capital letter.

Please read [this document](https://config9.com/apps/docker/docker-error-invalid-reference-format-repository-name-must-be-lowercase/) written specifically for this error.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue while using `docker` with `mlflow`.

In my case, the directory name containing my `Dockerfile` was ***"My Project"*** which I changed to ***myproject*** or ***my_project*** and It worked for me.
Also, follow the same naming format for all the root/super directories under which, the `Dockerfile` resides.

Not only for docker, but it's also good practice (especially in `Unix` based OS) to avoid the following while defining a directory name:-

- *white spaces*
- *camel-case*
- *upper-case*

Answer (score 3):

If you encounter this problem in go-swagger (Windows).

```
@echo off
echo.
docker run --rm -it --env GOPATH=/go -v %CD%:/go/src -w /go/src quay.io/goswagger/swagger %*
```

Use this instead: (add quote)

```
@echo off
echo.
docker run --rm -it --env GOPATH=/go -v "%CD%:/go/src" -w /go/src quay.io/goswagger/swagger %*
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}notificationsapi` 
with `image:notificationsapi` 
or     `image: ${docker_registry}notificationsapi`
in docker-compose.yml did solves the issue

file with error

```
  version: '3.4'

services:
  notifications.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}notificationsapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ../Notifications.Api/Dockerfile
```

file without error

```
version: '3.4'

services:
 notifications.api:
    image: ${docker_registry}notificationsapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ../Notifications.Api/Dockerfile
```

So i think error was due to non lower case letters it had

Comment: Great! In my case, my service was called frontendDev so I renamed it to frontend.dev and everything works again :)

Answer (score 2):

sometimes you miss -e flag while specific multiple env vars inline

e.g.
bad: `docker run --name somecontainername -e ENV_VAR1=somevalue1 ENV_VAR2=somevalue2 -d -v "mypath:containerpath" <imagename e.g. postgres>`

good: `docker run --name somecontainername -e ENV_VAR1=somevalue1 -e ENV_VAR2=somevalue2 -d -v "mypath:containerpath" <imagename e.g. postgres>`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a naked `--env` switch, i.e. one without an actual variable name or value, e.g.:

```
docker run \
   --env \       <----- This was the offending item
   --rm \
   --volume "/home/shared:/shared" "$(docker build . -q)"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was with the space in volume mapping that was not escaped. The jenkins job which was running the docker run command had a space in it and as a result docker engine was not able to understand the docker run command.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the docker registry as of today (sha `2e2f252f3c88679f1207d87d57c07af6819a1a17e22573bcef32804122d2f305`) does not handle paths containing upper-case characters. This is obviously a poor design choice, probably due to wanting to maintain compatible with certain operating systems that do not distinguish case at the file level (ie, *windows*).

If one authenticates for a scope and tries to fetch a non-existing repository with all lowercase, the output is

```
(auth step not shown)
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET https://$LOCALREGISTRY/v2/test/someproject/tags/list
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"test/someproject","Action":"pull"}]}]}
```

However, if one tries to do this with an uppercase component, only 404 is returned:

```
(authorization step done but not shown here)
$ curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET https://docker.uibk.ac.at:443/v2/test/Someproject/tags/list

404 page not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this changing some uppercase words on my `Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM Base as Build
RUN npm run Build:prod
```

to

```
FROM base as build
RUN npm run build:prod
```

Another place:

```
FROM Base as Release
COPY --from=Build /usr/path/here/dist/ ./dist
```

to

```
FROM base as Release
COPY --from=build /usr/path/here/dist/ ./dist
```

Answer (score 1):

If you come here after encountering this error in your GitHub Actions worflows…

Make sure to use [`docker/metadata-action`](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action) action to handle repository naming for you. Just call it before `docker/build-push-action`:

```yaml
# Add this
- id: docker-metadata
  uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
  with:
    images: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}

# Use the extracted metadata
- uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
  with:
    tags: ${{ steps.docker-metadata.outputs.tags }}
    labels: ${{ steps.docker-metadata.outputs.labels }}
    … other properties …
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and for some reason it appears to have been cause by uppercase letters in the Jenkins job that ran the `docker run` command.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the spaces in the current working directory that came from `$(pwd)` for map volumes. So, I used `docker-compose` instead.

The `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  react-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

Answer (score 0):

**"docker build -f Dockerfile -t SpringBoot-Docker ."**
As in the above commend, we are creating an image file for docker container. commend says create image use file(*-f refer to docker file*) and -t for the target of the image file we are going to push to docker. the "." represents the current directory

solution for the above problem: provide target image name in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Docker can build images automatically by reading the instructions from a Dockerfile. A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands a user could call on the command line to assemble an image. 
example:
    FROM python:3.7-alpine
The 'python' should be in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to run postgres through docker. Initially I was running as :

`docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test_password POSTGRES_USER=test_user POSTGRES_DB=test_db --rm -v ~/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name pg-docker postgres`

I was missing **-e** after each environment variable. Changing the above command to the one below worked

`docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test_password -e POSTGRES_USER=test_user -e POSTGRES_DB=test_db --rm -v ~/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name pg-docker postgres`

Answer (score 0):

I wish the error message would output the problem string. I was getting this due to a weird copy and paste problem of a "docker run" command. A space-*like* character was being used before the repo and image name.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers above did not work for my case, so I will document this in case somebody finds it helpful. The first line in the dockerfile `FROM node:10` for my case, the word **node** should not be **uppercase** i.e `FROM NODE:10`. I made that change and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case DockerFile contained the image name in mixed case instead of lower case.

Earlier line in my DockerFile

```
FROM CentOs
```

and when I changed above to `FROM centos`, it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the Name of the Docker-Image and not your File Name :P

$ docker run {your image}

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this error is that in your Dockerfile you have mixed capitalization in the syntax declaration itself. For example:
`# syntax=docker/Dockerfile:1`
instead of
`# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to other answers, there was a syntax error in my run command.  I typed a space instead of an underscore in an environment variable, `ENABLE SASLAUTHD` vs `ENABLE_SASLAUTHD`.
Adding the underscore  `_`  fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker-compose and you get that error, check the name of your services, no upper case letters allowed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error can also appear if you are running a docker run command in a gitlab pipeline which wraps over multiple lines in the pipeline editor. The error is caused when there is a space in one of the parameter names. To find it out, copy over the command to an editor with word wrap switched off, find the offending space and then go back to the same location in the gitlab pipeline editor and keep hitting backspace until the entire parameter name appears together in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an automatically generated CI/CD variable with uppercase characters—such as `${CI_PROJECT_PATH}` in Gitlab—for a tag, it's possible there is another similar [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for this purpose. In this specific case, switch the variable to `${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}` to <strike>resolve the error</strike> get a new error. (Namely, the slash between your user/group name and repository name gets replaced with a dash, so registry access is denied.)

Unless someone cracks this nut, **define the registry URL manually and use that for each tag argument**.