# Docker Deploy HDP error: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I tried increasing the disk space on docker and my sandbox container got removed. I have been trying to deploy it since then. But having the same error:

```
MINGW64_NT-10.0
+ sed -i -e 's/\( \/[a-z]\)/\U\1:/g' sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
+ chmod +x sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
+ sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I have made sure that the path has no spaces and even tried re-installing docker.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a login problem against the registry.

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/hortonworks/sandbox-hdp/manifests/2.6.5: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
```

you are probably logged with your email while you should be logged with your hub username instead.

Comment: I logged in. Sandbox-hdp is deployed but sandbox-proxy is still giving error. Question updated.

Comment: well, it will be useful to see any information that you could share about the code inside proxy-deploy.sh, the message looks self-explanatory "repository name must be lowercase"

Comment: Yes. But I am trying to read the file, there is nothing like the repository name.

Comment: Then it should be a wrong alignment of parameters used by the script like in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522615/docker-error-invalid-reference-format-repository-name-must-be-lowercase