# Docker run: invalid reference format error

Tags: docker, azure-cognitive-services, azure-container-instances, docker-run

I am trying to install and run azure cognitive-services Computer Vision Read containers.I am getting this error in cmd

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried to run below cmd

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 --memory 7g --cpus 2 \
containerpreview.azurecr.io/microsoft/cognitive-services-read \
Eula=accept \
Billing=xxxx \
ApiKey=xxxx
```

Note: i have replaced Billing and ApiKey details for security reason.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Check if 2 agent instances trying to use the same folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52818152/596285

Comment: Is there a `latest` tag of the image that you stored in the ACR?

Comment: @CharlesXu :i have pulled the image using 'docker pull' on my local machine where docker is installed and not through ACR. when i run the cmd 'docker  images' i can see the tag latest for this image.

Comment: Do you mean you have pulled the image from ACR to your local machine? Can you share a screenshot of the images in your local machine?

Comment: @CharlesXu : No, I have pulled it from docker hub to my local machine. I have upload the image screenshot in my main post.

Comment: Can you also share a screenshot of how you run the docker command?

Comment: @CharlesXu : shared the screenshot of the docker cmd on main post

Comment: Any more questions? Or if it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear to see when you separate the `docker run` into several lines in cmd, it cannot cognize it. So I recommend you don't separate the command, just let it in one line. Or you can do it in PowerShell and change the `\` like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Charles it worked :) . i run it in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that different shells have different syntax.

- For sh/bash-like shell, multiline escape char is `\`.
- For powershell, use `` ` ``.
- For cmd, it is probably `^`.