# Bash script doesn't set environment variable correctly

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, environment-variables

I am trying to set environment variables in a bash script to be read by another bash script, but they are not getting set properly.  I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

setting environment variables in a script:

```
setenv.env
  export DB1_IMAGE="postgres:latest"
```

run it:  . setenv.env

```
test it:  echo $DB1_IMAGE
result: postgres:latest
```

script to test the environment variable value:

```
test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $DB1_IMAGE
if [[ $DB1_IMAGE ==  "postgres:latest" ]]
then
  echo "equals"
else
  echo "not equals"
fi
```

run the test script:  . test.sh

```
result:  
     postgres:latest
     not equals
```

now set the environment variable with command line:

```
export DB1_IMAGE="postgres:latest"
```

now run the test script again:  . test.sh

```
result:  
     postgres:latest
     equals
```

Summary:  When an environment variable is set with a bash script, that value will fail an equals comparison in another bash script.  When that same environment variable is set with a command line, it passes the equals test.  I can't explain why this is.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  How could the == test fail?  Are there unprintable characters being inserted somehow?  Please help..

Comment: The docker compose yaml is the only way to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52818152/596285

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have listed this a a docker problem.  Sorry for the mis-understanding.  It manifested itself as  docker problem, but I've traced it to the root cause of a bash script problem.  I should have explained myself better.  This should be a bash script problem.  It is in fact reproducible from the .env file and the test script file.  It would only take anyone a few minutes to re-create it.

Comment: Hi @SamMelehy - do you get the same behaviour with single `[` rather than doubles `[[` - see https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#SCOMPARISON1

Comment: Make sure `setenv.env` does not have DOS-style `\r\n` line endings. You won't be able to see the `\r` with `echo` but the extra character will make the comparison not equal.

Comment: @MrR. Yes, just tested that and exact same result.

Comment: @glennjackman I suspected that, but i'm not sure how to tell.  I was originally using a windows based editor Komodo, with remote ftp connection to the source files on the Ubuntu server.  I then tried to recreate the file with SSH and nano.  Same result.  How can I tell definitively if there are dos-style line breaks?

Comment: @glennjackman You're right.  I ran $ file setenv.env and the result is setenv.env: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators.  It's DOS.  Thank you!

Comment: If you do `cat -A setenv.env` then the carriage returns should show up something like `^M`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @glennjackman, the cause of this was that the bash script file (setenv.env) was DOS-formatted as opposed to UNIX-formatted.  This means it had \r\n line breaks, which cause hidden characters to be inserted into the environment variables.  The fix is to run dos2unix on the file (sudo apt install dos2unix)

Comment: @komeilmajidi: They can't. The answer they found most useful was left as a comment, not an answer, so they can't accept it. It's pretty standard practice for OPs to reiterate an answer from the comment in order to confirm that their question was resolved, and to allow them to mark the answer as accepted. (Personally, I usually submit these answers as community wiki's and give the original commenter the opportunity to submit their own answer, but that's obviously not required.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney the question has been closed as dupe, so I'm not sure this apply here